# "Email a link" for blog posts doesn't work as expected

Tags: 2013, email, blog

I have a blog subsite which displays the following links underneath a post(on the Post.aspx page):

[image]

When I click on "Email a link" I get a mailto popup box but the body of the email is auto set to "&subject=Test".  I'm assuming this isn't the expected functionality since it's kind of useless.  My original thought was that my custom master page could be messing it up but I switched to a default and had the same issue.  Anyone else run into this?

Comment: i tried on my blog site and i get the same thing...just subject no link

Comment: 1. Which browser and email client are you using?
2. Can you copy the html of the link from the webpage using the 'View source' and put it here?

Answer (score 2):

I also had similar issue. The issue got solved by adding the 'Blog tools' webpart in the `post.aspx` page. Once I added this functionality it started working fine.

Comment: Thanks, it works. It may be one of the weirdest bug I have seen. If you do not want to see the Blog Tools you can minimize the web part and set the Chrome Type to 'None' and it still will fix the issue.